# Is there a way to catch stack overflow in a process? C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, recursion, stack, redhat

I have this following code which goes into infinite recursion and triggers a seg fault when it exhausts the stack limit allocated to it. I am trying to capture this segmentation fault and exit gracefully. However, I was not able to catch this segmentation fault in any of the signal numbers.

(A customer is facing this issue and wants a solution for such a use-case. Increasing the stack size by something like "limit stacksize 128M" makes his test pass. However, he is asking for a graceful exit rather than a seg fault. The following code simply reproduces the actual issue not what the actual algorithm does).

Any help is appreciated. If something is incorrect in the way I am trying to catch the signal please let me know that too. To compile: g++ test.cc -std=c++0x

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

int recurse_and_crash (int val)
{
    // Print rough call stack depth at intervals.
    if ((val %1000) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\nval: " << val;
    }
    return val + recurse_and_crash (val+1);
}

void signal_handler(int signal, siginfo_t * si, void * arg)
{
    std::cout << "Caught segfault\n";
    exit(0);
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int signal = 11; // SIGSEGV
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        signal = std::stoi(std::string(argv[1]));
    }

    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = signal_handler;
    sa.sa_flags   = SA_SIGINFO;

    sigaction(signal, &sa, NULL);
    recurse_and_crash (1);  
}
```

Comment: `int signal = 11; // SIGSEGV` wut? Why not `int signal = SIGSEGV`? `#include <signal.h>` No, there is no `signal.h` in C++. There is `csignal`, `cstdio`, `cstdlib`, etc. I think  `sigaltstack` might interest you.

Comment: A problem I see is that `recurse_and_crash` is being called because it's doing some useful work. If a SIGSEGV is caught and the recursion is unwound, that useful work doesn't get done. Maybe a partially complete answer is better than a crash, so you want to limit the number of times `recurse_and_crash` is called. Maybe `recurse_and_crash` is now a helper function that initializes a rucursion counter and then calls the recursive function, which returns on N number of function depths.

Comment: Of course, if it really is infinite recursion (although it doesnt sound like it since increasing the stack solves the crash?), that sounds like a bug in the function. If the input space `S` causes infinite recursion, then the function documentation at least needs to be updated that this is not a valid input space.

Comment: Isn't a signal handler a routine, which shall be _called_ in case of a signal? If so, the routine can be always sucessfully called - possibly except when there is no stack space available....

Comment: Make a counter, and have it output how deep the recursion has progressed.  When the application crashes, note the last counter value that was output.  Add a bit of code so that when the recursion counter gets to that number, have it throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the information! @KamilCuk I think the signalstack is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JohnFilleau, Eljay: Sorry for the incomplete information. Its not as simple as recurse_and_crash (...). The real usecase is more like a tree traversal with an enormously similar pattern in the syntax tree. The algorithm is more like A (...) calls B (...) -> C(...) to call A (...) which again calls B and C to process the pattern. The real bug which I see is the way the tree is generated but that simply can't be changed. And that is also the reason increasing the stack size fixes the issue because we now have more space to work with. Thanks for your inputs though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a surprisingly complex problem to solve. I will at this point not give working code, but rather focus on a few "nifty" issues that you have - or, as you continue coding for this - will encounter.

First, why are you recursing ?

The reason for that is that while signal handlers are "execution context transfers", *by default they do not have their own stack*. That means if you receive a signal as a consequence of an overflown stack, the signal handler will attempt to allocate space-on-the-stack for context potentially passed to it - and that simply re-throws the same signal again.

To make sure signal handlers run on their own separate / preallocated stack, use `sigaltstack()`  and the `SA_ONSTACK` flag for `sigaction()`.

Second, depending on "how badly" the stack overruns (your test program may not trigger this but a real world program may), the memory access (attempt) that's "the overflow-effecting action" may end up with *other* signals but `SIGSEGV`.

Your example "unspecifically" catches all signals, but that may in practice be rather insufficient / rather confusing - you sending your app a `SIGUSR1` or the shell/terminal sending it a `SIGTTOU` on being backgrounded are absolutely not indicative of a stackoverflow.
This means there's another issue - which signals are to be expected when making an "out of stack" memory access as consequence of a stack overflow ? And how can you know that a specific signal you got was *due* to a *stack access* ?
The answer to that again is more complex than first sight:

- if the stack overflow is "small enough", it's conceivable that it's within a guard page (a valid mapping, but deliberately unreadable) and it'll trigger `SIGSEGV`.
- if (no guard pages are used and) the access were to an unmapped memory region, you'll receive a `SIGBUS` instead.
- Even certain CPU instructions may make a difference whether access to "invalid memory address X" results in `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS` (For example, on x86, certain instructions raise `#GP` while others `#PF` - for the same mem address read/write - and the Linux kernel translates one possibly to `SIGBUS` the other to `SIGSEGV`)
- if there happens to be *other memory* mapped where this access happens (say, you've got `char local_to_blow_stack[1ULL << 40]; memset(&local_to_blow_stack, 0, 1);`) and just-so-as-it-happens something else valid is at "whatever your stack is minus a terabyte"), that access will in fact just-work. Without the compiler to create you "assist" code to identify such accesses, it's actually possible you've blown the stack and still make a number of successful / non-signaling memory accesses before eventually hitting a mem region triggering a signal.
- You may receive these signals for *other invalid* operations but *stack* access. Heap access, memory-mapped file/device access could possibly result in the same as well.

So "just catching signals", even "catching all signals that may possibly occur as a consequence of a stack overflow" is insufficient. You need, *within the signal handler* to decode the memory access location, *and* possibly the operation / cpu instruction, to verify that the memory access attempted actually was a "stack access out of bounds". It is possible for a thread to retrieve its own stack boundaries - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getattr_np.3.html can  be used for this, at least on Linux (`_np` implies 'non portable' - this isn't guaranteed to be available on all systems, others may have different interfaces to retrieve this information) - but ... to find the memory location that was accessed depends on the signal and accessing instruction again. *Often* (but not *always*) it's in the `siginfo` (the `si_addr`) field.

From what I remember, exactly which signals fill `si_addr` under exactly what circumstances, and whether the address in there is e.g. the *instruction* issuing the memory access or the *memory location* of the attempted access, is somewhat system- and hardware-dependent (Linux may behave differently from Windows or MacOSX, and different on ARM than on x86)
So you would also need to validate that "the `si_addr` in this `siginfo_t` is somewhere-near the signaled thread's stack", but possibly also validate that the instruction that caused it was actually a memory access / `si_addr` can be "traced back" to the *instruction* that faulted. That (finding the *faulting instruction's address* / the program counter) ... requires decoding the *other* argument for the signal handler, the `ucontext_t` ... and there you're deep deep deep [ recurse infinity here ] in HW / OS specifics.

At this point I'd like to terminate; a "simple" but not perfect solution just needs an alternate signal stack, and the handler to retrieve the current stack boundaries via `pthread_getattr_np()`, to compare the `si_addr` against. If your life or that of others depends on the correct answer, remember the above though.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate explanation. It looks like a fairly difficult task to implement and get it working seamlessly across architectures. This is very helpful!

Comment: For a "perfect" score, yes I agree it's hard. A "likely good enough" approach though will only need the two things named in my last paragraph, using `sigaltstack()` and making the signal handler (for `SIGSEGV` / `SIGBUS`) compare `si_addr` against the lower stack limit obtained from `pthread_getattr_np()`. Such a check won't have _false positives_ - if it says "yes this was a failed mem access just-below the bottom of the stack" then so it is. But it may _miss_ a few (corner)cases, where your crash _was_ caused by a stack overflow but not a "normal" one.